# Meaning of "for a suitable $f$ in the definition of kernel pair.

Tags: category-theory, definition

The following definition is taken from $\textit{Theory of Categories}$ by Barry Mitchell

Definition:  For $f:B\rightarrow D$ in the category $C$, let

$$(1)\quad \begin{array}{ccccccccc} K & \xrightarrow{a} & B\\
{b}\big\downarrow & & \big\downarrow{f}  &  \\
B & \xrightarrow{f} & D 
\end{array}$$

be a pullback.  The pair $(a,b)$ is called a $\textit{kernel pair}$ of $f$.  A pair of morphisms $a,b:D\rightarrow B$ is called a kernel pair if it is a kernel pair for a suitable $f$.  Cokernel pairs are defined dually.

Question:  I would like to know what the last sentence: "A pair of morphisms $a,b:D\rightarrow B$ is called a kernel pair if it is a kernel pair for a suitable $f$" mean.  What does it mean by a suitable $f$?

Thank you in advance

Comment: You may disregard the word “suitable” here. It has no significance.

Comment: @ZhenLin I can just understand it to say "it is a kernel pair for $$"?
"

Comment: Yes. Maybe you want to add “there exists $f$ such that …”.

Comment: @ZhenLin, how about "iit is a kernel pair for some $f$?

Comment: Yes, that is semantically equivalent.

Comment: @CaptainLama thank you for affirming that.  :)